# How do I configure Putty for one character at a time>

Tags: putty

I'm using Putty version 0.73.  I want to transmit one character at a time so I'm try RAW mode.

But "RAW" mode sends a cr/lf if I press Enter. In RAW mode it should just send a CR.

I actually tried Rlogin a few times and that worked. But now it is asking for a user name.

So I tried Kitty but it has the same bug.

Does anyone know to make it send CR and not CR/LF?

Comment: Have you tried to paste the text including CR from clipboard?

Comment: I don't know what good that would be. I need to type, not paste.